# allure-behave adding links and custom labels

Tags: allure, python-behave

I followed official documentation from https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/master/allure-behave/examples/link.rst
But when I applied a link to my test, allure got the formatting wrong

`@allure.label.author:adrian @allure.issue:https://jira.o-t.com/browse/QA-793 @verified #8.11.23 Scenario: Create correlation from selection`

The link is translated into https:jira.o-t.combrowseQA-793 as it couldn't parse "/"
and no author label is added in the final report.

I replaced @allure.issue:https://jira.o-t.com/browse/QA-793 with @allure.issue:https3FA%2FAjira.o-t.com2FAbrowse2FAQA-793, as I've read is a hexal translation for urls.